# Conditional Count() in crystal report using where clause

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports-2008

How to get the result using formula field in crystalreport for counting number of records where fieldname ='PASSED', do i need to use where?

like: select count(*) as cnt from tbl where overallresult='PASSED'

This is my current code:
if {command.overallresult} = 'PASSED' then
count({command.overallresult})

Expected:
Count All row which is containing PASSED result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of query you can do following in crystal report.

Create a formula `@count` and place it in detail and supress.

```
if {command.overallresult} = 'PASSED'
then 1
else 0
```

now take the `sum`  of the formula in footer

Comment: Actually you don't even need to place the formula in the detail.  You can just create the formula and then use it.